# Combine several strings into one xml document vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, string, dictionary

I am trying to write several strings that contain the values of several dictionaries to a single XML file. What would be the best way to do this? I thought xDocument looked the best way, but i am struggling to write multiple strings to one document.

I intend to read from this XML file so it needs to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOrgive me if I am not understanding your question, but can't you just add a parent element " to contain all strings?

```
Dim sbUser As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sbUser.AppendLine("<?xml version=""1.0""?>")
sbUser.AppendLine("<root>")
sbUser.AppendLine("<services>")
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Users) In dictusers
    sbUser.AppendFormat("<Name>""{0}""<SessionID>""{1}""</SessionID><UserName>{2}</UserName></Name>", item.Key, item.Value.SessionID, item.Value.UserName).AppendLine()
Next
sbUser.AppendLine("</services>")
sbUser.AppendLine("<cpus>")
  ...
sbUser.AppendLine("</cpus>")
  ...
sbUser.AppendLine("</root>")
```